# How to avoid character's movement with the background image?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am making a game which has a skiing character. A background image will move right to left.

Now, my background is using a panel as implementation:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(......
```

and my character is using a picturebox:

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(....
```

I use a timer to set panel's location to achieve a scrolling map effect, the following is in the `timer_tick` event handler:

```
panel1.Location = new Point(mapX, 0);
if (mapX < -600)
{
    mapX = 0;
}
else
{
    mapX -= 10;
}
```

The problem I met is when the map is moving, my character is moving too, which is unexpected. I also tried to use `Controls.Add(picturebox1)` to let the `Form` control this component, and then my character disappeared.

Is there anyone who can help me fix it?

Comment: How do you paint character ? do you paint it on panel1? so character position is relative to panel1 (not relative to screen coords). if so, you need to move character right the same amount you move background to the left.

Comment: If you move the picture box in design mode over a panel, the designer will make the panel the parent. You need to dynamically create the picture box at runtime or make sure it is placed outside of the panel at designtime, I guess.

Comment: razor: I set picturebox's backgroundimage as role, and for some reason, I can use the way let role move with background as same speed.

Comment: Ross: I just tried dynamic generate a picturebox with role picture, but it still not appear in form(without `Controls.add(picturebox1)`), but if I add `panel1.controls.add(picturebox1)`, then role will move with background